# Find the minimal polynomial using Galois theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

One exercise in chapter 14 of Dummit and Foote is to find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$.  I know this can be done by computing higher powers of $\alpha$ and then finding a nontrivial relation among them, but I think the point of this question is to use Galois theory.

I think the solution to this question goes something like:

1. Note that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$.
2. The field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$.  For any $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})/ \mathbb{Q})$, the only options for $\sigma(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})$ are 
   \begin{equation*}
   \pm \sqrt{2} \pm \sqrt{3}
   \end{equation*}
3. Now form the polynomial:
   \begin{equation*}
   m(x): = \big( x - [\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}] \big)\big( x - [-\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}] \big)\big( x - [\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}] \big)\big( x - [-\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}] \big)
   \end{equation*}
4. This polynomial is the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, because:

   (a) It is monic.  This is obvious.

   (b) It is irreducible.  This can be seen from noting that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})$, and the fact that this is a degree $4$ polynomial and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}): \mathbb{Q}] = 4$.

   (c) Has $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ as a root.

   (d) Has coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$.  I guess this can be seen by just multiplying out the terms of $m(x)$.

> I don't have any questions about the correctness of the assertions in any of the above steps.  My questions are more related to why these steps are done in the first place.

- The assertion in Step 1 is obviously true, but why would anyone ever think to do this step in the first place?  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})$ is also contained in the Galois extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})$, so why not work with this extension instead?
- I understand that $\sigma(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}) = \pm \sqrt{2} \pm \sqrt{3}$.  But why should knowing this fact lead me to want to multiply together all the $(x - \sigma(\alpha))$?   This cannot just be an arbitrary trick...there clearly must be some connection here that I am failing to see.
- Is there are more elegant way (than just multiplying out the polynomial) to see that $m(x)$ has coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: (d) can be seen because the coefficients of $m(x)$ are fixed by any automorphism of the field, and hence they must be in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: $\alpha^2-5=2\sqrt{6}$ ... $(\alpha^2-5)^2=24$ ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason to choose $F=\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt 3)$ is that there is no non-trivial automorphism of this field which fixes $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$. That is not true for $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3,\sqrt 5)$.

If $p(x)$ is a rational polynomial, then for any automorphism $\sigma$ of $F$ and any $u\in F$, $\sigma(p(u))=p(\sigma(u))$. This is because $\sigma(r)=r$ for any rational $r$.

So if $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is a root, then so must be $\sigma(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$. So any rational polynomial with root $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ has to have $\sigma(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ for all $\sigma$.

Finally, the coefficients of $m(x)=\prod_{\sigma\in G}(x-\sigma(\alpha))$ are fixed by any automorphism of $\sigma'\in G$. In the above field, at least, the only elements fixed by *all* automorphisms of the $F$ are the rationals, so the coefficients must be rational.'

So $m(x)$ has all the roots it has to have, and it has rational coefficients, so it is the minimal polynomial.

---

So what we have is that

1. $m(x)$ has no repeated roots, by the consideration in the first paragraph, that there is no non-trivial automorphism of $F$ which fixes $\alpha$.
2. Any polynomial with rational coefficients which has $\alpha$ as a root has $m(x)$ as a factor.

From this, we see that $m(x)$ is irreducible - if it factors non-trivially, then there is a rational polynomial of smaller degree that has $\alpha$ as a root, but that must be divisible by $m(x)$.

---

So the two key properties we have is that:

1. If $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha$, then $\sigma=1$.
2. For $x\in F$, if $\sigma(x)=x$ for all $\sigma\in G$, then $x\in\mathbb Q$.

It's worth considering examples where this is not the case.

Taking $F=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$ and $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{2}$, there is one non-trivial automorphism, $\sqrt[4]{2}\mapsto -\sqrt[4]{2}$. But (2) isn't true here, since $\sqrt{2}$ is fixed by both automorphisms. So:

$$(x-\sqrt[4]2)(x+\sqrt[4]2)=x^2-\sqrt{2}$$ is not a minimal polynomial fo $\alpha$ over $\mathbb Q$.

The case where (1) fails is actually your $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$ example. You get repeated factors in this case.

---

One final note. There is a way to remove repeated roots. If $m(x)$ has repeated roots, you can remove them by computing:

$$m_1(x)=\frac{m(x)}{\gcd(m(x),m'(x))}$$

This has problems when your fields have finite characteristic, but over the rationals, this will always give you the minimal polynomial even when $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha$ for some non-trivial case.

Comment: So I see what you are saying about $\sigma(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})$ needing to be a root of the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$.  So $\prod_{\sigma \in G} (x - \sigma(\alpha)$ must divide the minimal polynomial.  But without checking that this product of the $(x - \sigma(\alpha))$  is irreducible, we don't if the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ has more roots than just the $\sigma(\alpha)$, right?

Comment: Well, it is trivial, once you show that this polynomial has rational coefficients, that it is irreducible. If it factored non-trivially, there would be a rational polynomial with $\alpha$ as a root but some $\sigma(\alpha)$ not a root. Since this polynomial has no repeated roots, it can't have a proper factor with all the roots. (The first paragraph essentially prevents repeated roots for this $m(x)$.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  One more question: I agree that for any $\sigma \in G$, $\sigma$ will fix all the coefficients of $m(x)$ when $m(x)$ is in the factored form $m(x) = (x - \alpha_1)(x - \alpha_2) \cdots (x - \alpha_n)$.  But when I multiply all this together (and get coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$), how do I know if $\sigma$ still fixes the coefficients?

Comment: If $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $F$, define an automorphism of the ring $F[x]$ as $\sigma'(ax^i)=\sigma(a)x^i$. (Show that this is an automorphism.) Then $\sigma'(x-\alpha)=x-\sigma(\alpha)$ and thus $\sigma'(m(x))=m(x)$, and hence $\sigma$ fixes each coefficient of $m(x)$.

Comment: Great, thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

The other roots of the minimal polynomials are the conjugates (images under $\sigma\in G$), that's what makes $\prod_{\sigma\in G}(X-\sigma(\alpha))$ such a good guess.
Incidentally, you *could* try the same with $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3,\sqrt 5)$, but that would - as you may easily find - produce the *square* of the minimal polynomial.